# How to set uploaded CSV file server path for __StringFromFile function in JMeter HTTP Request?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

How to set uploaded CSV file server  path for  `__StringFromFile` function in JMeter?
How to get  server CSV file path for this? ex Bitbucket
[need to run JMeter scripts in sever not in local machine]

Below screenshot shown local machine file path

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a parameterized User Defined Variable for the server name that will be passed in from the command line when the test is run:
`Name = server` `Value = ${__P(server,serverNameHere)}`

Then in your server name reference `${server}` in the path.

Comment: where should i set this --> Value = ${__P(server,serverNameHere)} ?

Comment: You can either set it in Config Element->User Defined Variables or at the top level Test Plan object.